# Correct the spelling of 'Colour' in member name 'ColorsValidatorMock.GetColourGroupLanguage()'

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, lint, sonarlint, hungarian-notation

**Error:** *Correct the spelling of 'Colour' in member name 'ColorsValidatorMock.GetColourGroupLanguage()' or remove it entirely if it represents any sort of Hungarian notation*

```
public static List<ColourGroupLanguage> GetColourGroupLanguage()
        {

        }
```

> **Color** and **colour** are different spellings of the same word. Color is the preferred spelling in American English, and **colour** is preferred in all other main varieties of English.

Am working with Sweden project So they are told we should use a method name with **colour** instead of **colour**. But The sonar lint is throwing above warning error.

Is it possible to change the configuration US English to UK English in visual studio sonar lint? Or pleas let me know if you have any idea to workaround this.

Comment: @john. The both meaning is same. But the Swedish guys are prefer to use **colour**  but sonar lint considering **color**. So what can I do because am Indian :( :(

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another extension installed in your Visual Studio? SonarLint does not have a spellchecker...